# In a CSV to access a two word header with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Consider this code:

```
$header = '#', 'Status', 'Affected Version', 'Priority', 'Subject', 'Description'
        $csv = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ' ' -Header $header
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
          $_.Description = "something"
        }
```

As you can see I am adding columns to a csv file and adding values to them.
Now my question is:
How should I access the 'Affected Version' column? 
I don't want to add a '_' between the words. The space must remain. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
... | ForEach-Object { $_.'affected version' = "Something" }
```

Comment: hello from the low quality post review queue

Comment: Hello from the low quality comment review queue :)